# How to add to a count based on column values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of a single row and I want to make a function that will add to three different counts based on the values in the columns. Example of the single row (alphabet being the column names):

```
| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i |
-------------------------------------
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
```

For example, I want the function to say if the value in column a is 1, count1 +=1, if the value in column b is 0, count2 +=1, if the value in column c is 1, count1 +=1 etc...
I've tried iterating through the columns but keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: can you provide your dataset?

Comment: it's gonna be *really* difficult to help you with a clear description of your requirements and showing us the code you've already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
if frame['a'][0] == 1:
    count1 += 1
elif ...
```

Assuming your frame is in a variable named 'frame', and you are able to just hardcode the relation between columns and the correct count variables. Because both 'a' and 'c' correspond to count1, it looks like you can't rely on a simply iterative abstraction.

Comment: This worked and was exactly what I wanted, I just had to use all "if" statements and not elif because the counts/columns are all independent of each other, thank you so much!